# Angular 2 selector with template content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular 2 with @ng-bootstrap.
I have a modal dialog like this:

```
<template #editDialog let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">MyHeader</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form">
            <label class="form-label" for="myinput">Caption: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myinput" [ngModel]="selected.Caption" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="c('true')">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="c('false')">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want to reuse the frame of the modal dialog and just want to change the body in my components. It should look something like that:

```
<my-modal>
    <div class="form">
        <label class="form-label" for="myinput">Caption: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myinput" [ngModel]="selected.Caption" />
    </div>
</my-modal>
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this, espacially with the model (selected.Caption)? I have tried a lot but didn't get it working.

**UPDATE**

To clearify:
I want to inject some HTML tags, so i get something like that:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <!-- MY CUSTOM HTML COMES HERE! -->
    <!-- MAYBE WITH <ng-content></ng-content> -->
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="activeModal.close(true)">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ((click)="activeModal.close(false)">Abbrechen</button>
</div>
```

The answer of @pkozlowski.opensource basically works with open and close the modal. But I do not get my body in there:

```
<my-modal>
    <div class="form">
        <label class="form-label" for="myinput">Caption: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myinput" [ngModel]="selected.Caption" />
    </div>
</my-modal>
```

Answer (score 2):

Modals implementation from the https://ng-bootstrap.github.io library make it very easy to re-use content - all you need to do is to create a component and use it as content. In your particular case you could create a component like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">My Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form">
        <label class="form-label" for="myinput">Caption: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myinput" [value]="selectedCaption" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="activeModal.close(true)">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="activeModal.close(false)">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class EditDialogContent {
  @Input() selectedCaption;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}
```

And then interact with `@Input` of this component: `modalRef.componentInstance.selectedCaption = 'Some caption';`. Here is a live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kRvBeFbvFR2ORInZAij7?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But I want to inject some HTML in the body, so that I only have to define the frame of the modal once. Please see my updated Post.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I found a solution, please see my own answer.

Comment: @der_chirurg cool, yes, this is one possible solution. And you can make it even simpler by using the `[ngTemplateOutlet]` directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zq3orr2DuHP2f5h6twrs?p=preview

Comment: That's great, I will use this simplified approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution how it works. Please see my Plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BNlsp2bGfWmae4K4ZTtT?p=preview

I have to inject a template into my modal view like this:

```
[...]
export class EditDialogContent implements OnInit {
    template: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}
```

And the corresponding HTML is:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">My Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <!-- THIS IS IMPORTANT! -->
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></template>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="activeModal.close(true)">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="activeModal.close(false)">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And the body template HTML is:

```
<p>You can pass an existing component as content of the modal window. In this case remember to add content component as an <code>entryComponents</code> section of your <code>NgModule</code>.</p>

<template #bodyTemplate>
  <div class="form">
    <label class="form-label" for="myinput">Caption: </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myinput" [(ngModel)]="selected.Caption" />
  </div>
</template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(bodyTemplate)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

To open the dialog simply do this in the component behind:

```
open(bodyTemplate) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(EditDialogContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.template = bodyTemplate;
    modalRef.result.then((closeResult) => {
      console.log(`Closed with: ${closeResult}`);
    });
  }
```

Thanks to [pkozlowski-opensource](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1418796/pkozlowski-opensource) for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make separate component for the modal.

And if you want to achieve that you only change body of the modal that will be something like this.

**modal.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
      @Input() title: string;
}
```

**modal.component.html**

```
<modal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <ng-content select="body-of-modal"></ng-content>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
    <ng-content select="footer-of-modal"></ng-content>
    </div>
</modal>
```

Important part here is **`<ng-content>`**

How that works?

Now if you want to re-use your modal component is some other component following your example it will be something like this:

**your example:**

```
<modal #editDialog title="My Header" let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <body-of-modal>
        <div class="form">
            <label class="form-label" for="myinput">Caption: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myinput" [ngModel]="selected.Caption" />
        </div>
    </body-of-modal>
     <footer-of-modal>
        <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="c('true')">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="c('false')">Cancel</button>
    </footer-of-modal>
</modal>
```

This example is not 100% correct and probably I made some typos, but I just wanted to try to explain you on a simple example how it works.

I hope so that you understand. If not don't hesitate to ask if something is not clear from above example.